# Populate array from an object array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I've got the following object that's an object array (an array of objects), on a variable:

variable: myVar1

On fireBug I get the following lines when I call myVar1:

```
[Object { myId= "1", myName= "Name1" }, Object { myId= "2", myName= "Name2" }, Object { myId= "3", myName= "Name3" }]
```

I need this data to be in the followng format stored on a variable too:

```
myVar2 = [
[1, 'Name1'],
[2, 'Name2'],
[3, 'Name3']
]
```

I've tried so many things like the use of for loops and js functions but can't get it work.
I supose it's so easy. Anyone could try to explain the procedure.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution for browsers which support [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var result = arr.map(function(o) { return [+o.myId, o.myName]; });
```

For compatibility you may use the [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility) provided at **MDN**.

Comment: Thank you. Only a curiosity: Which browsers does not support array.map() function?

Comment: @CalypoGunn IE < 9. You can check it here: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/.

Answer (score 1):

The following should do the trick:

```
var myVar2 = [];
for (var i = 0; i < myVar1; i++) {
  myVar2.push([myVar1[i].myId, myVar1[i].myName]);
}
```